# Maximum length of EFI variable name

Tags: uefi

What is the maximum length of an EFI variable name? I cannot seem to find this information in the manual.

It seems that `MaximumVariableSize`, returned by `QueryVariableInfo()`, does not include the name overhead. From the UEFI manual:

"The `MaximumVariableSize` value will reflect the overhead associated with the saving of a single EFI variable with the exception of the overhead associated with the length of the string name of the EFI variable."

What maximum length should I enforce on EFI variable names? I can choose something reasonably small (e.g., 100 bytes), but this could break on some machines, and regardless, I want to use the firmware-imposed limit.

Comment: I think  there’s no defined limit. I took a quick look at Tiano, and it seems to just take the length of the string passed in and allocate that much space. So, if there is enough memory for the allocation, any length name should work.

Comment: Other than stating that  the maximum supported variable size must be at least 32kB, the UEFI specification is silent on this issue.

Comment: @prl Thanks. Do you have advice on how to proceed? I suppose I should check two conditions: 1. The name length is less than `MaximumVariableSize` (or should it be the sum of the name length and the contents to set?). 2. The sum of the size of the name and the size of the variable content to set is less than `RemainingVariableStorageSize`. If both conditions hold, it is safe to set a variable with the given name and data.

Comment: @fpmurphy Thanks. See my above comment. Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: No, I don’t think you should do *any* checks. Just call **SetVariable**. It will do any necessary checks and return an error status if they fail.

Comment: The check in SetVariable is “StrSize(VariableName) + DataSize <= MaximumVariableSize”. So you *could* do that check, but another  implementation could do it differently, so you’ll be better off to just let the implementation do the check.

Comment: Note, StrSize(str) is (strlen(str) + 1) * sizeof *str.